# Issues with SVG Scaling across devices/screen sizes

Tags: html, css, svg

I attempting to create an 'abnormal' polygon that covers a section of my page using the SVG tag. However, when I scale the page, the object disappears from view. How do I make the SVG remain visible when scaling?

Cheers

```css
.about {
    /* Keeps the div fixed in one position */
    position: fixed;
    /* Removes White surrounding boxes */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* Sets the Width and height of the div, and the background colour */
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #141311;
} 

svg {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
    <svg height="100%" width="100%">
        <path d="M1000 0 L1280 0 L1280 700 L900 700 Z"  fill="#FEFEFA"  />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a bit of javascript to resize its width/height and  its viewBox value.
See the example below.

```html
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.about {
    /* Keeps the div fixed in one position */
    position: fixed;
    /* Removes White surrounding boxes */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* Sets the Width and height of the div, and the background colour */
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: blue;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="about">
    <svg>
        <path d="M1000 0 L1280 0 L1280 700 L900 700 Z"  fill="red"  />
    </svg>
</div>
</body>
<script>
//--onload, onresize----
function sizeFull()
{
    var mySVG=document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]
    var svgW=window.innerWidth
    var svgH=window.innerHeight
    var bb=mySVG.getBBox()
    var bbx=bb.x
    var bby=bb.y
    var bbw=bb.width
    var bbh=bb.height

        mySVG.setAttribute("viewBox",bbx+" "+bby+" "+bbw+" "+bbh )
        mySVG.setAttribute("width",svgW)
        mySVG.setAttribute("height",svgH)
}
sizeFull(); //---init window---
document.addEventListener("onload",sizeFull(),false)
window.onresize=sizeFull
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. However, Is there anyway I can adjust the placement of the SVG so it situated on the right? As when I try adjust the values of the SVG is stays very close to the center of the page.

Comment: @Fjcym - Yes, try:  var bbx=bb.x-300  Or, you can include any offset value, rather than 300, until you like the placement.